# Cash On Delivery fee based on Dokan vendors count in WooCommerce

Tags: php, jquery, woocommerce, dokan, fee

In WooCommerce Dokan multivendor shop I have Cash On Delivery (COD) payment for customers.

I created a code that counts the vendors in the cart and multiply them with the fee that i want per vendor. on my example is 2 € per vendor. so lets say that we have 1 product of each vendors(for now we have 2 vendors) on the cart. That should be 2 * 2 = 4€ total cost of COD.

That is working perfectly but when I received the order I see the fee only in main order and not in the suborders. it should be 2€ in one suborder and the other 2€ in the other suborder.

That has been working the whole time but since 11.02.2021 it suddenly stopped. Any ideas that could help me ?

Here is the code that I am using:

```
// 2 € Fee COD - Add a custom fee based on cart subtotal: 
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'custom_fee_for_dokan', 999, 1 );
function custom_fee_for_dokan ( $cart ) {
    $car_items  = WC()->cart->get_cart(); // Cart items

    $items_sort = array(); // Initializing

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $car_items as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        // Get the vendor_id
        $vendor_id   = get_post_field( 'post_author', $cart_item['product_id'] );
    
        $store_info  = dokan_get_store_info( $vendor_id ); // Get the store data
        $store_name  = $store_info['store_name'];          // Get the store name
    
        // Set in multidimentional array the vendor and then the cart item key
        $items_sort[$store_name][$cart_item_key] = $vendor_id;
    }

    if ( count($car_items) > 1 ) {
        ksort( $items_sort ); // Sorting by vendor name
    }

    $vendors = 0;

    // Loop by vendor name
    foreach ( $items_sort as $store_name => $values ) {
        $vendor_id  = reset($values); // The vendor id
        $store_url = dokan_get_store_url( $vendor_id );  // Get the store URL (if needed)
        $vendors++;
    } 

    // End of Loop

    $flatrate = $vendors * 2;

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( ! ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) )
        return; // Only checkout page

    $payment_method = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_payment_method' );

    if ( 'cod' == $payment_method ) {
       // $surcharge == $vendors;
        $cart->add_fee( 'Pay on delivery', $flatrate , true );
    }
}

// jQuery - Update checkout on methode payment change
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'nik_checkout' );
function nik_checkout() {
    if ( ! ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) )
        return; // Only checkout page
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        $('form.checkout').on('change', 'input[name="payment_method"]', function(){
            $(document.body).trigger('update_checkout');
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The issue is related to **Dokan plugin** that **does not split the fee by suborders anymore** in the plugin recent versions. So you should ask Dokan support, **to check if it's not a bug introduced on last updates** or if it's not a new available setting.

Now your code is outdated and complicated for nothing. It can **really be simplified and optimized**.

The following code will set a COD fee based on dokan vendors count:

```
// COD Fee based on vendors count 
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'dokan_cod_fee_vendors_based' );
function dokan_cod_fee_vendors_based ( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;
    
    // Only checkout page
    if ( ! ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) )
        return;
        
    $fee_by_vendor = 2; // HERE set the fee by vendor
    $vendors_array = array(); // Initializing

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
        $vendor_id = get_post_field('post_author', $item['product_id']); // Get the vendor_id
    
        // Set in an indexed array to get how many vendors
        $vendors_array[$vendor_id] = $vendor_id;
    }

    $fee_total = count($vendors_array) * $fee_by_vendor; // Get fee total by vendor

    if ( 'cod' === WC()->session->get( 'chosen_payment_method' ) ) {
        $cart->add_fee( 'Cash On Delivery Fee', $fee_total, true ); // Apply the fee
    }
}

// jQuery - Update checkout on methode payment change
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'payment_refresh_checkout_js' );
function payment_refresh_checkout_js() {
    // Only checkout page
    if ( ! ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) )
        return; // Exit
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        $('form.checkout').on('change', 'input[name="payment_method"]', function(){
            $(document.body).trigger('update_checkout');
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Comment: it works but on the suborders in i dont see the pay on delivery fee.it should say 2€.it doesnt split it anymore